# Fetching database with variable

Tags: php, mysql

I'm attempting to have a database pulled with a variable.

```
$username = $_SESSION['user_username'];
$req = mysql_query("select id, username, message from '$username'_inbox");
while($dnn = mysql_fetch_array($req))
```

or this..

```
$username = $_SESSION['user_username'];
$req = mysql_query("select id, username, message from '$username'");
while($dnn = mysql_fetch_array($req))
```

I just need a solution to fetch a database user related.

Comment: mysql_ is deprecated try to user mysqli_*

Comment: So what is the problem exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> mysql_* is deprecated try to use mysqli_*

1) Mysql query should be

**select id, username, message from table_name where username='potato'**

2) Use prepared statement or PDO when you use user data in query . to avoid sql injection .

```
       $servername = "localhost";  //host name

        $username = "username"; //username

        $password = "password"; //password

        $mysql_database = "dbname"; //database name

    //mysqli prepared statement 

        $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password) or die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());

       mysqli_select_db($conn,$mysql_database) or die("Opps some thing went wrong");


    $stmt = $conn->prepare("select id, username, message from table_name where username=?");

        $stmt->bind_param('s',$username);

        //The argument may be one of four types:

        //i - integer
        //d - double
        //s - string
        //b - BLOB
        //change it by respectively 

        $stmt->execute();

        $result= $stmt->get_result();
        $rows  =$result->num_rows;

        if($row>0)
        {
            while($row=$result->fetch_assoc())
            {

                print_r($row);

            }


        }
        $stmt->close();
         $conn->close();
```

Comment: I edited it, I'm trying to have it fetch the database name with the unique username.

Comment: really didn't get what your trying to say @Art . i think your trying to fetch user detail from table for particular user isn't it ?